# background image dosnt show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a weird problem. I'm testing stuff before I start working on a site, so I'm making different pages with different images in them.

I'm working with a image I did in photoshop (background image), and for some reason it doesn't show on the page in Chrome, FireFox, or IE9.

Here is the simple code in css:

```
body 
{
   width:auto;
   height:1000px;
   background:red images\BackGroundBig.jpg repeat-y fixed top ;         
}
```

Is there something wrong with that?

When I change this to only: `background-color:red`, it's showing as a red background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong syntax:

```
background:red url("images/BackGroundBig.jpg") repeat-y fixed top ;
```

Comment: thanks, but its still dosnt show the image only the red background.

Comment: maybe you path is wrong... basedirectory is your css file. i bet 100 euro on background:red url("../images/BackGroundBig.jpg") repeat-y fixed top ;

Comment: @ggzone: `url("/images/BackGroundBig.jpg")` might work also :-P

Comment: ggzone was right url("../images/BackGroundBig.jpg") this what fixed that thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Separately you can get it like these

CSS properties used for background effects:

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

Altogether

```
background:Color url("path") repeat x y;
```